# htaccess 410 url spam hack requests excluding site generated request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bots, spam

Our site was hacked and links to random content where added to the site. We completely removed the hacked site and put a new one in its place. Everything new including images and content, no other part of the old site was used.

The problem we have now is that the hacker has submitted 100,000's of links to the search bots and the server is continuously visited every 1 second by the bots trying to index the links that don't exist and have never existed on the old and the new site.

We have tried to combat this using the htaccess file of the site with several instances of various conditions and rewrite rules that tell the bots the content is gone.

Example

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/product/.*

RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
```

The trouble with this is that some requests are getting through and producing 301 and 404 errors.

This is causing the bots to retest the request again and report our site as having 100,000s of bad links.

I am looking for a solution that returns 410 code to the bots for all requests excluding all source requests that our actually part of the site.

The site only has approx 10 pages but is a Joomla CMS so there are a mass of resources that get loaded in the background to deliver the page.

My idea was to visit each page in the site and use the browsers inspect to gather a list of all resource requests that a page makes.

The question is how do I formulate this into conditions and rules for the htaccess so that all page requests including route / are delivered but the hackers links requested by the bot aren't?

Also we are working on sending emails to the bot's to say their requests are being instigated by the hacker.

Comment: You could use `robots.txt` to lock out any crawlers that follow this standard, and later allow them in again.

Comment: This question may fit better on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ as it's not really about programming.

Comment: This is a webmastering question and better suited to the Webmasters stack (as mentioned above).

Comment: Thread moved to: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119099/htaccess-410-url-spam-hack-requests-excluding-site-generated-request

Robert if the robot.txt file is used to lock out any crawlers this will include our site pages. The Hack has damage our site reputation with the search to a large degree, I would prefer not to add to this while we are working on this to reignite this. With that said, using robot.txt block all crawlers is a quick and dirty way to get the job done if you're not concerned about them not seeing your site for a while.